# Want to make a lookup like in pic and want the background of it to be the ViewController that i present this popup from

Tags: swift, xcode11, swift5

[image: Want to make like this]

that is my code to present lookup

```
  let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EmployeeLookUpVC") as! EmployeeLookUpVC

        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Answer (score 0):

Give Transparent color to the super view of EmployeeLookUpVC.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

> Add this code snippet from where you want to lunch popup.

```
let popupViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “PopupViewController") as? PopupViewController

let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

//You can set the background color as you want
popupViewController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.6) 

popupViewController!.view.frame = (window?.frame)!
window?.addSubview(popupViewController!.view)
window?.rootViewController?.addChild(popupViewController!)

popupViewController!.didMove(toParent: self)
```

> Add this code snippet on the popup close button action.

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview()
self.removeFromParentViewController()
```